# How to know if my carrier is pick up in-store

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I have a prestashop module in which they are asking me in a parameter to indicate if the carrier that was chosen is to pick up in store or not. I am getting the carrier information in this way

```
$carrier = new Carrier($cart->id_carrier);
```

This brings me the information of the carrier correctly, the problem is that the only parameter I see to know if it is pick up or not is `delay`, but this is a parameter which you can always change the value in the carrier configuration.

When creating the store in prestashop this creates 2 carrier by default, one is the pick up in-store, but if I delete this carrier and then I want to create another custom that is pick up in-store, prestashop does not provide a specific option to check that this carrier is of this specific method, the closest thing is the `delay` but this can change in many prestashop stores.

There is some method, parameter or function that tells me 100% if the carrier is pick up in-store, a parameter or something that never changes in any prestashop store?

Comment: Hi
Did you find a solution for that ? I'm facing same issue...

Answer (score 0):

Every carrier has `id_reference` in database, it is something what is always same, as you might know, every time you edit Carrier in PrestaShop, a new instance is created and inserted into database, `id_reference` field helps you track original `id` of Carrier.